# cygwin xterm to open multi session from script

Tags: shell, cygwin, ksh, rhel

I have .ksh script with below commands to open multiple session on different server but not able to execute file parallel same time.any help ?

```
 xterm -e ssh appuser@appserver1; cd /usr/bin/; ./script1.ksh sleep 5 &
 xterm -e ssh appusr@appserver2; cd /usr/bin/; ./script2.ksh
```

where cd and script[12].ksh commands should run on remote host.

Not able to view script running/executing on 2 different windows same time.

I have tried below command ,but it's opening two sessions simultaneously not parallel.Like not opening 2 windows same time to execute sessions.

```
xterm -hold -e ssh appuser@appserver1 'cd /usr/bin;./adauto.sh psswd &'
xterm -hold -e ssh appuser@appserver2 'cd /usr/bin;./adauto.sh psswd;'
```

Thanks,
SM

Comment: what do you mean by "not able to execute file parallel same time".  Isn't the `&` at the end of your first cmd working? Did you try `xterm -e ssh appuser@appserver1 'cd /usr/bin/; ./script1.ksh ; sleep 5' &`? (and possibly other quoting options) . Please update your Q with this information and don't reply in comments. Good luck.